AWS CDK unable to see role property in patterns.ScheduledFargateTask constructor
I am trying to deploy aws FargateScheduledTask service using CDK python. I am unable to see the role property in the patterns.ScheduledFargateTask constructor to assign the events role. Please can you let me know what I am missing here.
    # Create schedule task
    scheduledtask = patterns.ScheduledFargateTask(
        self, "Fargate_Service",
        cluster=cluster,  # Required: Provide the cluster
        scheduled_fargate_task_definition_options=scheduled_task,
        schedule=autoscaling.Schedule.expression("cron(30 11,12 * * ? *)"),  # Required: Define the schedule
        desired_task_count=1,
        security_groups=[ecs_sg],
        **role=eventrole** ------- This one
    )


Which role are you trying to specify?

I am trying to send 'eventrole' as it uses event bridge to attached schedule task. You can see the similar question in this thread. But I could not find answer here. https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/pull/17980
